# Отображение виджетов с QLayout и без QLayout в PyQt

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, qlayout, qgridlayout

В одном окне на вкладке `tab1` должно отображаться видеоизображение с вебкамеры и график, который обновляется на нажатие кнопки.

Размер окна, виджетов и размещение на окне должны быть фиксированными.

У меня получилось поместить график и видеоизображение на `QHBoxLayout`. Но не отображаются при фиксированном размещении (при задании положения и размера виджетов) на вкладке `tab1` в классе `MyWidget()`, а не `MainWindow()`.

Почему я так делаю - в итоге мой график должен принимать значения из таблицы и обновляться при нажатии на ячейку таблицы и это уже реализовано в классе `MyWidget()`.

1 Вариант размещения с помощью 'QHBoxLayout()' (работает):

```
import numpy as np
import sys    
from PyQt5.Qt import *    
import random    
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        global kolichestvo_tochek
        global y
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)    
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tab1 = QWidget()
        self.layout_1 = QHBoxLayout()                
        self.tab1.setLayout(self.layout_1)
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1, 'tab1')
        # График
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.layout_1.addWidget(self.canvas)            
        self.update()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.sc = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        # Камера
        self.viewfinder = QCameraViewfinder()
        self.cameraInfo = QCameraInfo.defaultCamera()
        self.camera = QCamera(self.cameraInfo)
        self.camera.setViewfinder(self.viewfinder)    
        self.layout_1.insertWidget(0, self.viewfinder)
        if self.camera.status() != QCamera.UnavailableStatus:
            self.camera.start()

    # Реакция на нажатие Enter на нампаде! клавиатуры
    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        k = e.key()
        if k == 16777221:
            super().keyPressEvent(e)
            self.update()     

    def update(self):                        
        global y
        self.ax.clear()
        x = np.arange(1, 6)
        y = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=5)
        self.ax.plot(x, y)            
        self.canvas.draw()   


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)            
        self.resize(1500, 470)
        self.widget1 = MyWidget(self)                        
        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.widget1)


class MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName("WebCam")
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

---

2 Вариант без 'layout'  (не работает):

```
import numpy as np
import sys    
from PyQt5.Qt import *    
import random
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        global kolichestvo_tochek
        global y
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)    
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tab1 = QWidget(self)
        # График
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)    
        self.update()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.sc = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        # Камера
        self.viewfinder = QCameraViewfinder()
        self.cameraInfo = QCameraInfo.defaultCamera()
        self.camera = QCamera(self.cameraInfo)
        self.camera.setViewfinder(self.viewfinder)
        if self.camera.status() != QCamera.UnavailableStatus:
            self.camera.start()    

    # Реакция на нажатие Enter на нампаде! клавиатуры
    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        k = e.key()
        if k == 16777221:
            super().keyPressEvent(e)
            self.update()        

    def update(self):                        
        global y
        self.ax.clear()
        x = np.arange(1, 6)
        y = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=5)
        self.ax.plot(x, y)            
        self.canvas.draw()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)            
        self.resize(1500, 470)            
        self.widget1 = MyWidget(self)                        
        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        central_widget = QTabWidget()            
        central_widget.addTab(self.widget1, "tab1")
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        
class MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)   
 
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName("WebCam")
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Напишите в вопросе что именно работает и что не работает, и как должно работать то что не работает.

Comment: Не понятно что вы хотите сделать и почему так вы решили сделать, попробуйте объяснить лучше. Как-то покажите что вы хотите получить в окне и что должно происходить если размер окна изменить?

Comment: Спасибо что сделали уточняющий вопрос! Я откорректировал и уточнил текст своего вопроса. P.S. это моя первая программа PyQt5 и все виджеты размещены с помощью автокомпоновщиков 'QH/VBoxLayout' , но когда увидел, что интерфейс получился не совсем удобным, решил разместить всё фиксированно и не могу понять как заставить отображаться графику и видеоизображению. В действующем коде виджеты располагаются как в первом варианте кода, поэтому хотелось бы минимальными изменениями заставить его работать. Я знаю, что существует 'spacer', но у меня динамически появляющиеся кнопки и для меня это не подходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Виджет без родителя - это окно.
   Поэтому все что мы хотим показать в главном окне должно иметь родителя,
   виджет на котором мы будем показывать.
2. Расположение виджетов - это также отдельная большая тема.
   **Я не могу рекомендовать абсолютное позиционирование,
   потому что не вижу в этом необходимости и этот способ не практичный**. 
   Рекомендую вам основательно изучить тему  [**Layout Management**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)
3. Вы не показали изображение, которое у вас получается
   и изображение, которое вы хотите получить.
   Я увидел вашу задачу так:

---

```
import sys 
import numpy as np
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *    
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent) 
        
        self.viewfinder = QCameraViewfinder()
        self.cameraInfo = QCameraInfo.defaultCamera()
        self.camera = QCamera(self.cameraInfo)
        self.camera.setViewfinder(self.viewfinder)    
        if self.camera.status() != QCamera.UnavailableStatus:
            self.camera.start()

        self.figure = Figure()                     
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='voltage (mV)',
               title='About as simple ...')
        self.ax.grid()

        self.frame_right = QFrame()
        self.frame_right.setStyleSheet("background-color: #F4A460;")
        layout_frame_right = QGridLayout(self.frame_right)

        column = 2 
        many_button = 7
        for step in range(many_button):
            btn = QPushButton(f'btn{step+1}')
            btn.setStyleSheet("""
                background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
                color: rgb(85, 255, 127);
                font-size: 11px;
            """)            
            row = step // column
            col = step % column
            btn.clicked.connect(lambda ch, b=btn, r=row, c=col: 
                print(f'{b.text()}, [{r}, {c}])'))        
            layout_frame_right.addWidget(btn, row, col)  
        

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(5, 2)
        
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.viewfinder, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.frame_right, 0, 2, 2, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.setRowStretch(0, 3)
        layout.setRowStretch(1, 2)
        layout.setColumnStretch(0, 4)
        layout.setColumnStretch(1, 4) 
        layout.setColumnStretch(2, 2) 
        
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        if key in (Qt.Key_Enter, Qt.Key_Return):
            self.update()  
        else:
            super().keyPressEvent(event)
        

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)            
        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.central_widget.setObjectName("central_widget")  
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.qtabwidget = QTabWidget(self.central_widget)  
        self.qtabwidget.setObjectName("qtabwidget")

        self.tab_1 = MyWidget(self)
        self.tab_1.setObjectName("tab_1")
        self.qtabwidget.addTab(self.tab_1, "Tab 1")
        
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.qtabwidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "Tab 2") 
     
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(f'<center>Hello Tab3</center>')
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.qtabwidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "Tab 3")   

        self.frame_bottom = QFrame()
        self.frame_bottom.setStyleSheet("background-color: #D2691E;")
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.frame_bottom)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel(f'<center>Frame_Bottom</center>'))
        self.frame_right = QFrame()
        self.frame_right.setStyleSheet("background-color: #B8860B;")
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.frame_right)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel(f'<center>Frame_Right</center>'))

        self.layout = QGridLayout(self.central_widget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.qtabwidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.frame_right, 0, 1, 2, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.frame_bottom, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.layout.setRowStretch(0, 5)
        self.layout.setRowStretch(1, 2)
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(0, 7)
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(1, 2)


Stylesheet = '''
#central_widget {
    background-color: #008080;
}
#qtabwidget {
    font-size: 15px; 
}
#qtabwidget::pane {
    border: 1px solid #008080;
}
QTabBar::tab {
    background: #F4A460;
    padding: 3px 7px;
}
QTabBar::tab:hover {
    background: #FF7F50;
}
QTabBar::tab:selected {
    background: #FFFF00;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #F00;
}
QTabBar::tab:!selected {
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
#tab_1 {
    background-color: #FFFAF0;
}
#tab_2 {
    background-color: #800000;
}
#tab_3 {
    font-size: 25px; 
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    color: #FF00FF;
}
'''

        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet) 
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    app.setApplicationName("WebCam")
    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(970, 560)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]